# Как создать функцию с аргументами которые внутри неё

Tags: javascript, функции

Пытаюсь сделать функцию ,чтобы не дублировался код, но не пойму, как именно передать аргументы функциям внутри, т.к. значения задаются именно внутри данной функции. Может кто-нибудь подскажет, как исправить дублирование, либо упростить код, заранее спасибо!

```
for (pivotRow = 0; pivotRow < rows; pivotRow++) {
    for (pivotCell = 0; pivotCell < cells; pivotCell++) {
        for (currentCell = pivotCell + 1; currentCell < cells; currentCell++) {
            setCurrentDirValue(currentCell, pivotRow);
            setPivotDirValue(pivotCell, pivotRow);
            if (checkNearValue(currentDir, pivotDir)) break;
        }
    }
}
for (pivotRow = 0; pivotRow < rows; pivotRow++) {
    for (pivotCell = 0; pivotCell < cells; pivotCell++) {
        for (currentCell = pivotCell + 1; currentCell < cells; currentCell++) {
            setCurrentDirValue(pivotRow, currentCell);
            setPivotDirValue(pivotRow, pivotCell);
            if (checkNearValue(currentDir, pivotDir)) break;
        }
    }
}
```

А именно аргументы этих функций:

```
setCurrentDirValue(currentCell, pivotRow);
setPivotDirValue(pivotCell, pivotRow);

setCurrentDirValue(pivotRow, currentCell);
setPivotDirValue(pivotRow, pivotCell);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как один из вариантов, просто передать параметром желаемый вариант вызова функций.

```
function fill(isSwap = false)
{
    for (pivotRow = 0; pivotRow < rows; pivotRow++) {
        for (pivotCell = 0; pivotCell < cells; pivotCell++) {
            for (currentCell = pivotCell + 1; currentCell < cells; currentCell++) {
                if(isSwap) {
                    setCurrentDirValue(currentCell, pivotRow);
                    setPivotDirValue(pivotCell, pivotRow);
                } else {
                    setCurrentDirValue(pivotRow, currentCell);
                    setPivotDirValue(pivotRow, pivotCell);
                }
                if (checkNearValue(currentDir, pivotDir)) break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

И вызвать нужный из кода

```
fill(true);
fill(false);
```